# PHP: Secure Authentication ONLINE/OFFLINE application

Tags: php, angularjs, rest, middleware, slim

I am creating a rest based application using php [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/) + [Eloquent ORM](http://www.slimframework.com/news/slim-and-laravel-eloquent-orm) and [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/). I want to create a secure authenticate system in my application such that it can run in both environment(ONLINE/OFFLINE). Actually I am concern about the OFFLINE mode, if any client copy my code and pasted into another computer system then it will work without any problem. So I want to prevent this such that the in every 1st launch of application it will validate the user key then the application will open otherwise it will say "Unauthorize User"

Please give me some suggestion to build dektop/offline application using PHP.

Here is my code which I am using currently for ONLINE mode... It fails when software is in OFFLINE(because of internet connection).

```
// route middelware for simple API authentication
function authenticate(\Slim\Route $route) {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    $uid = $app->request->headers("uid"); //$app->getEncryptedCookie('uid');
    $username = $app->request->headers("username"); 
    $password = $app->request->headers("password"); 
    $key = $app->request->headers("key"); 
    if(validateUserKey($uid, $key) === false) {
        $app->halt(401, "Unauthorize User");
        if(validateUserLogin($username, $password) === false) {
            $app->halt(200, "Invalid Username and Password");
        }
    }   
}

function validateUserKey($uid, $key) {
    // I am maintaining a table which has my client list with the API key so 
    // this function will hit a url to my server like(www.dev-server.com/validateKey?uid=$uid&key=$key) for authentication
}

function validateUserLogin($username, $password) {
    //it will validate the uname and password in from local DB
}
```

Comment: About the code pasted on another computer, you're talking about injecting the key header with the token you're generating?

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP is a server-side language and I'm assuming you don't want to ask your users to run their own web server in order to use your application without an internet connection, PHP is not really part of the equation here.

In other words; you will have to solve your problem in your client side application, ie using HTML, Javascript and local storage, if you intend to allow your users to continue using your application without an internet connection. Your question is not specific enough to tell you how to do that, but [Google is your friend](https://www.google.com/search?q=offline%20web%20application).

With regard to user authentication; since clients are basically outside of your control, I advise you focus on security on the server side of things; for example, require an internet connection for authentication once, keep the credentials in local cache and allow the user to use your application without further checks while they're offline, then ask them to re-authenticate when they come back online and want to push the changes made offline back to the server.

Without more information about your application and how it's being used, it's difficult to say exactly how to go about this, hope my thoughts can be of help.

Comment: I know you're generally not supposed to +1 in comments, but Wilbo is right here. On the client side, you don't have PHP, so you'll want the application to run locally without the need for auth. The auth should happen when the user is connected to the internet and sends or retrives data from your server.